# javascript function not calling

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to check the pass and repass both are same or not?
    but the problem is onkeyup event is not calling the check function.
    path of javascript file is also proper.

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="signUp" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- Username -->
            <label for="username" class="lbl-content">
                Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name="inputUsername" class="input-txt" placeholder="Username"
                    autofocus required />
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="lbl-content">
                Password</label>
            <div class="">
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" class="input-txt"
                    placeholder="password" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Re password -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="re-password" class="lbl-content">
                Re-Password</label>
            <div class="">
                <input type="password" id="inputRepassword" name="inputRepassword" class="input-txt"
                    placeholder="re-password" onkeyup="return check()" required />
                <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

JavaScript function in which i am checking the pass and repass values..

```
    function check() {
        var pass = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value;
        var repass = document.getElementById('inputRepassword').value;
        var msg = document.getElementById('confirmMessage').value;
    if (pass1 == repass1) {
            document.getElementById('inputRepassword').style.backgroundColor = green;
            document.getElementById('confirmMessage').innerHTML = "Password Match";
            alert("hello");
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "pass match";
            return true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('inputRepassword').style.backgroundColor = red;
            document.getElementById('confirmMessage').innerHTML = "Password did not match";
            return false;
        }
}
```

Please help me. Where am I wrong?

Comment: `red` has to be `"red"` and `green` has to be `"green"`.

Comment: You stored both passwords in variables pass and respass but compare variables pass1 and repass1.

Comment: you had typos in your code.

Comment: ya that i corrected but i was trying to with getElementByName. i forgot to change that :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error may be cause by below two line as green and red is not javascript key word

```
document.getElementById('inputRepassword').style.backgroundColor = green;
document.getElementById('inputRepassword').style.backgroundColor = red;
```

insted of this you need to pass this value as string "green" and "red". so code will be

```
document.getElementById('inputRepassword').style.backgroundColor = "green";
document.getElementById('inputRepassword').style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

You made some typos, here is your code fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/gaus7uhm/

```
function check() {
    var pass = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value;
    var repass = document.getElementById('inputRepassword').value;
    var msg = document.getElementById('confirmMessage').value;
    if (pass == repass) {
        document.getElementById('inputRepassword').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        document.getElementById('confirmMessage').innerHTML = "Password Match";
        alert("hello");
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "pass match";
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('inputRepassword').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        document.getElementById('confirmMessage').innerHTML = "Password did not match";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here are all the changes I made to your code:

```
pass1 => pass
repass1 => repass
red => "red" (you need to pass a string, not a variable)
green => "green"
```

Another way to fix the red/"red" problem is to declare these variables at the beginning:

```
var red = '#711',
    green = '#171';
```

This way you can customize your colors and you won't have to search in your code where you set the colours.